# May I apply for a UK Visa extension from within the UK with Indian passport validity of less than 6 months?

Tags: uk, visa-extensions, visa-expiration

I am an Indian citizen and residing in UK and currently hold Tier 2 ICT visa and due for extension of my VISA, but I heard that for VISA extension one should have passport with minimum 6 months validity , unfortunately I hold only 5 months valid passport, can still apply for visa extension or not ?

Comment: Have you applied for a new passport?

Comment: How long an extension do you want to apply for?

Comment: I have been trying to apply for new passport but not getting any appointments , have been monitoring on daily basis.

my VISA due to expire on 12th July and passport on 14th Dec , it has got 5+ months validity and I'm planning to apply for 2 years VISA extension , but as per guidelines 6 months minimum validity is required